# Button setOnclickListener is not working with expandable listview

Tags: android

i have two xml for the expandable list view and listitem.

```
1) list.xml
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/gradient_bg"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ExpandableListView
    android:id="@+id/lvExp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

   </LinearLayout>

2)list_group.xml
  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/lbl"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_login"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:text="Login"
    android:focusable="false" />

  </RelativeLayout>
```

Now i have created the following class where i have written all code for expandable list view and it works perfect but the button is also visible when i write the btn_login.setOnCliclListener then it give force close error.

Allitem.java

```
Button btn_login;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.list);

     btn_login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_login);

        btn_login.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
     ....
     ....
   }
```

All work perfect but when i write setOnClickListener for that button but i gettin below error

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.example.test.list.onCreate(list.java:45)
```

so how can i solved this?

Comment: Inside adapter class you have to access button and set the onclicklistener there

Comment: "btn_print" where is in your xml. why you used this??

Comment: sorry it is btn_login.

Comment: where is the list.java ?

Comment: Still getting exception???

Comment: @sanatshukla i have adapter class for expandable list view.

Comment: Add button onClick Listener in your adapter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to handle onClickListener of your list item button in the Adapter of the listview.

Answer (score 1):

Edit your button variable to btn_print instead Btn_login .. Btn_login is your xml button id..

Button btn_print;

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.list);

 btn_print = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_login);

    btn_print.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
});
```